# Qt 5.0.2 wont Compile

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5

I've just installed Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 500 MB) (Info) and trying to accomplish the "hello world" tutorial
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_for_beginners_Hello_World

However when I press Run the project doesn't build at all, I mean the folders for build are created which are empty, plus I dont have any error generated.

My configuration is Win64 Pro with VS2012 installed. On Option Window and on Compilers Tab I have MS Visual C++ 11 correctly recognized. On Qt Versions Tab I don't have any errors. On Kits tab I have a worning sign indicating that Debugger is not found (normally it shouldn't break the building process). Can someone assist on this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I found the answer. It seems QT don't like non-Unicode characters in Project Path.
Once I moved my projects to C:\ everything started to work

Answer (score 0):

well use this ligne in the .pro
`    TEMPLATE = app
    TARGET = name_of_the_app

```
QT = core gui widget
```

`